# Mal-funcionamento do site após alteração no .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Para um site ficar com url mais amigável eu removi o `.php` utilizando os seguintes comandos dentro do `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Funcionou perfeitamente para a parte de noticias.php, e o site www.exemplo.com.br abre sem a necessidade de adicionar index.php.
No entanto, o problema está no painel administrativo, que se faz necessário eu adicionar index. Ficando obrigatoriamente nessa forma:

```
www.exemplo.com.br/painel/index
```

ou

```
www.exemplo.com.br/painel/index.php
```

Como posso solucionar isso? Acessar apenas com /painel/

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Só está faltando o `RewriteBase /` deixe seu código assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Alterei o htaccess conforme sugeriu porém ainda não funcionou! Continuo não conseguindo acessar por www.exemplo.com.br/painel e acessando apenas via www.exemplo.com.br/painel/index

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Eu utilizo esta regra abaixo para poder ter esse efeito.
Eu possuo uma pasta e dentro dela um arquivo **index.php** comum.

**Exemplo:**

www.meusite.com.br/dashboard/novo-cadastro/

1. O *dashboard* é uma pasta;
2. O *novo-cadastro* é uma pasta;
3. Dentro da pasta *novo-cadastro* possui um arquivo index.php
4. No *.htaccess* que está na raiz do projeto, há a seguinte regra:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.meusite.com [NC]
       RewriteRule (.*) https://hecato.com/$1 [R=301,L]
       RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.hecato.com
       RewriteRule (.*) index.php?user=%1
   </IfModule>
   ```

Caso não resolva, sugiro que crie outro *.htaccess* dentro do diretório que você quer criar essa regra (no caso, a pasta /painel).

Qualquer dúvida estamos aí.

Espero ter ajudado